# JavaScript Files Registered in Parent Theme Won't Load When Calling wp_enqueue_script() in Child Theme?

Tags: themes, theme-development, javascript

I'm making a framework parent theme and in the parent `functions.php`, I want to register all the possible js files I use frequently and if I want it to load it, in the child `functions.php` I just have to use `wp_enqueue_script()`.

But it doesn't work...

Any clue why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The child functions.php file loads before the parent functions.php, so you're registering them after enqueueing them. Try enqueueing the scripts on a hook, like `'after_setup_theme'` instead.

Comment: Nice gonna tcheck this right now!!!

Comment: Thanks working perfectly... but I put it on the     'init' hook

Comment: I'll still advise against splitting things up like this - registering scripts in the parent file and enqueuing them in the child file might work for your uses, but it makes it more difficult on developers who come along later and want to build a new child theme - they have to reproduce all of you enqueuing code to make it work.  A child theme is supposed to *modify* the parent, not reproduce the parent's original child theme ...

Answer (score 0):

It's bad form to split your code like that.  You should *always* have your functions and the hooks that call them located in the same location to make it easier to debug.

That said, if you place your `wp_enqueue_script()` calls in the parent theme's `functions.php`  file, do things work like they're supposed to?  If not, there might be something else going on ... and we'd need to see your code to diagnose and fix it.

Comment: In general I agree with your comments about bad form but I think it doesn't apply in this use-case. What he *@Eduplessis* is doing in his parent theme is essentially the same that WordPress does in `wp_default_scripts()` in `/wp-includes/script-loader.php`; i.e. he's registering his custom scripts using `wp_register_script()` so his child themes need only call the simpler form of `wp_enqueue_script()` instead of having to specify the script's full file name and path from the parent's theme directory. FWIW.

Comment: I agree that the pattern has its uses ... but I'm coming from the background of having to debug poorly documented child themes and trying to help clients figure out when different functions are called on their site.  Since `wp_register_script` and `wp_enqueue_script` work together, having them in different files can make it incredibly hard to track things down later.

Comment: thanks for your comments. A themes framework without any documentation is bad... or any project in gen. but since this themes framework it's only to speed up my developpment and I always make a little doc...

i think it's the right choice to put all register all my script in my parent and the specific load in child... exactly like WordPress do with all js included by default.